# Blackberry Jde FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, blackberry-jde

What do i do to resolve this problem?

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException:C:\Program Files\Research In Motion\BlackBerry JDE 4.2.1\bin\Settings.rc(Access is denied)
```

Answer (score 0):

Verify that the file exists and the user executing the process has access to the file.